# Is it possible to have move information about app's failure on Google Play Developers Console?

Tags: java, android, google-developers-console

In google play console developers console I have access to stack trace generated by users after my application fails. There is a lot of invaluable information about what's going on. Here's an example:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5753)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at componentspinout.ammsoft.componentspinout.ComponentViewActivity.onCreate(ComponentViewActivity.java:83)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6112)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1117)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
```

Unfortunately, with the stack trace show above I can only guess the problem. I know it's a NullPointerException inside my class ComponentViewActivity, on method onCreate (line 83). My question is, is it possible to have more information?

If the program was running inside Android Studio I can use LOG.e to log information about classes and variables to help me understand the problem. How can I do something similar using google console stack trace?

Comment: If you use Firebase, you can know it